# List to list of dictionaries with openpyxl defined_name range

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm reading from a named range in Excel and generating a list.  I need it to be a list of dictionaries with the first row of the named range used for dictionary keys.

So my spreadsheet is this:

[image]

My code is this:

```
ws, range= next(wb.defined_names[col[0]].destinations)                
            values = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in wb[ws][range]]
```

I'm getting this:

```
[['Country', 'Capital'], ['England', 'London'], ['France', 'Paris'], ['Scotland', 'Edinburgh'], ['Norway', 'Oslo'], ['Finland', 'Helsinki'], ['Spain', 'Madrid'], ['Germany', 'Berlin']]
```

But I need this:

```
[{'Country': 'England, 'Capital': 'London'}, {'Country': 'France, 'Capital': 'Paris'}.......]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get the keys from the first row and use them to create dictionaries for the rest.

Comment: `[dict(zip(a[0], v)) for v in values[1:]]`

Comment: No button to accept the answer with zip, but it's working great, thanks!